# C# Multi-Client socket Chat Application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

I'm a newbie C# socket programmer and I'm trying to create a C# socket chat application...
here are the requirements of the app..
*it can accept more than one client.
*it should handle those new client on a separate thread.
*the server has a list of active clients and displays them in a list(GUI)
*the server should know when a client is disconnected and will remove it from the list(probably a hashtable or array) of active clients.

honestly, I don't know where to start.
I've been reading through various articles on the net about sockets, multithreading and the likes, but I'm still a bit confused about the whole client/server interaction thing..
Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.. :D

Comment: Start by learning to use the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#-MQ-in-a-Hundred-Words). It was designed for applications like you're describing, works very well, and is free.